# tensorflow.distribute.MirroredStrategy crashes jupyter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

Here is my sample code which I want to run on multiple GPUs:

```
Python 3.6.9 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jul 30 2019, 19:07:31) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)
>>> strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
2019-10-03 01:31:40.996949: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2019-10-03 01:31:41.202104: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1640] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: Tesla M60 major: 5 minor: 2 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.1775
pciBusID: 0000:88:00.0
2019-10-03 01:31:41.204216: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1640] Found device 1 with properties: 
name: Tesla M60 major: 5 minor: 2 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.1775
pciBusID: 0000:89:00.0
2019-10-03 01:31:41.206891: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1640] Found device 2 with properties: 
name: Tesla M60 major: 5 minor: 2 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.1775
pciBusID: 0000:b1:00.0
2019-10-03 01:31:41.208973: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1640] Found device 3 with properties: 
name: Tesla M60 major: 5 minor: 2 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.1775
pciBusID: 0000:b2:00.0
2019-10-03 01:31:41.210742: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1640] Found device 4 with properties: 
name: Quadro P620 major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.354
pciBusID: 0000:3b:00.0
2019-10-03 01:31:41.212942: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.0
2019-10-03 01:31:41.238005: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10.0
2019-10-03 01:31:41.250276: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10.0
2019-10-03 01:31:41.253403: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10.0
2019-10-03 01:31:41.282306: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10.0
2019-10-03 01:31:41.298864: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10.0
2019-10-03 01:31:41.680756: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2019-10-03 01:31:41.700545: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1748] Ignoring visible gpu device (device: 4, name: Quadro P620, pci bus id: 0000:3b:00.0, compute capability: 6.1) with core count: 4. The minimum required count is 8. You can adjust this requirement with the env var TF_MIN_GPU_MULTIPROCESSOR_COUNT.
2019-10-03 01:31:41.700587: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1763] Adding visible gpu devices: 0, 1, 2, 3
2019-10-03 01:31:41.730124: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 AVX512F FMA
2019-10-03 01:31:42.529773: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x557fadad7e70 executing computations on platform CUDA. Devices:
2019-10-03 01:31:42.529852: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor device (0): Tesla M60, Compute Capability 5.2
2019-10-03 01:31:42.529879: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor device (1): Tesla M60, Compute Capability 5.2
2019-10-03 01:31:42.529897: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor device (2): Tesla M60, Compute Capability 5.2
2019-10-03 01:31:42.529914: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor device (3): Tesla M60, Compute Capability 5.2
2019-10-03 01:31:42.665047: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 2100000000 Hz
2019-10-03 01:31:42.681099: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x557fade9e890 executing computations on platform Host. Devices:
2019-10-03 01:31:42.681154: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor device (0): <undefined>, <undefined>
packet_write_wait: Connection to 192.168.134.68 port 22: Broken pipe
```

I can see that the `tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()` line crashes the system. You can probably see that the connection also gets closed.

Can you please help ?

Comment: Looks like you lost connection with your remote host. Check this blog post to see some possible solution https://thomas-cokelaer.info/blog/2017/05/packet_write_wait-connection-to-xxx-broken-pipe/

Comment: Hi , no it is not coincident. I can observe every time , I run something on GPU , jupyter server gets stuck and eventually the connection is broken.